# Copied Code works, written code does not?

Tags: python, python-turtle

New Python programmer here. I'm trying to write Snake in python without the use of tutorials. I'm now working on key binds, but I'm running into a problem

```
#Move snake to the left
def move_right():
    right = snake.xcor()
    right += 20
    snake.setx(right)

#Key bind "d" 
wn.listen
wn.onkeypress(move_right(), "d")
```

The above code is supposed to move the snake to the right when the "d" key is pressed, but it does not work. However, when copying code from a fully functioning Pong program from a tutorial on YouTube, it does work. The copied code is this:

```
#Function for paddle_b_up
def paddle_b_up():  
    y = paddle_b.ycor() 
    y += 20  
    paddle_b.sety(y)  

#key bind to the up arrow key
wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_up, "Up")
```

I then proceeded to write out the copied code, exactly as it was written in the Pong program, into the Snake program and it does not work. I am very confused. The indenting is the same, the code is the same (save a few different, but consistent variables), and only the movement and key binding code from the Pong program was copied into the Snake program. Without changing anything else, the Pong code works, but only when I copy and paste the code into the Snake program. Any advice? Thank you.

Comment: you forgot `()` in `listen()`. And remove `()` from `move_right` in `.onkeypress(move_right, "d")`. `onkeypress` needs only function's name without `()` - it is called `callback`. As you can see working code has `paddle_b_up` without `()` in `wn.onkeypress(paddle_b_up, "Up")`

Comment: Not sure how I missed the lack of parenthesis in paddle_b_up, but, it's working now. If you don't mind, could you explain why parenthesis isn't required? I learned in another python tutorial that parenthesis were required in callback. And I did have the () in wn.listen but forgot to add them here when re-writing the code. Thanks!

Comment: parenthesis executes function at once but you want to execute it later - when you press key - so you sends only function's name and it will use `()` to run it when you press key. It is popular in many languages and function's name as argument is called `"callback"`

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the difference between the two calls to `wn.onkeypress()`. In the copied code there's no `()` after `paddle_b_up`, but in your code you have `move_right()`.

When you put `()` after a function name it calls it immediately. But you want the function to be called later, when the key is pressed. You need to pass a reference to the function, not the result of calling the function.

```
wn.onkeypress(move_right, "d")
```

You also need `()` after `wn.listen` so you call the function.

Comment: Hi Barmar! Thanks for the explanation. Not sure how I missed the lack of parenthesis in paddle_b_up, but when I removed them from move_right, the code works. Could you explain why the parenthesis aren't required? I learned in other Python programs parenthesis are required. Granted, the tutorials weren't using turtle, but I'm still curious. Perhaps I'm just remembering it wrong? And I did write wn.listen() in the original code but forgot to write it here, lol. Thanks again!

Comment: I explained it in my answer. You put parentheses when you want to call the function. You don't want to call the function when you're telling it what to do when the user pressed a key. You want the function to be called when the key is pressed.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you!